# "How to Fix Xampp Error with Ioncube Loader"

Tags: xampp, ioncube

I've installed Xampp on windows 10 laptop, my php files needs ioncube loader which i've installed 
but there is a problem after copying ioncube_loader_win_5.6.dll into php/ext folder and made changes to php.ini file where i need to put a line "zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\ioncube_loader_win_5.6.dll"

after doing this my phpmyadmin page don't work gives the below error
Warning: require_once(/byte_safe_strings.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in on line 57

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/byte_safe_strings.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in on line 57

if i remove the ioncube_loader_win_5.6.dll file, the phpmyadmin page works

can anyone help me sort this problem?

Comment: Unless you're forced not to update, as PHP 5.6 is EOL I'd recommend first switching to the XAMPP for PHP 7.1 or 7.2. As a side effect of that the issue you have may go away.

Comment: I've upgraded the xampp for 7.1 and ioncube loaders for the same but now this error shows up:C:\xampp\htdocs\unlockdeal\index.php was encoded by the ionCube Encoder for PHP 5.0 and cannot run under PHP 7.1. Please ask the provider of the script to provide a version encoded with the ionCube Encoder for PHP 5.6. in Unknown on line 0

Comment: In this case try asking the script provider to give you scripts built to work on PHP 7. ionCube support (ioncu.be/S) might be able to help with reaching out to the creator if necessary. Disclosure: I am associated with ionCube.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the creator of the script is no longer in contact with me, is there any other way to run this properly? Also, why dont it run in php 5.6 in my shared hosting it gives this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /path to file//functions.php on line 1642.   all though the script is proper there is no syntax errors.

Comment: The main issue with some files on Windows should be resolved in Loader 10.3.2 due for release release later today or tomorrow. If any other issue persists after the update then contacting ionCube support is the best thing. Also if you create a ticket saying that you'd like to get hold of updated files, they may be able to get in touch with the script creator for you.

Comment: yes the problem is solved with the latest loader but now its gives me error for unexpected end of file in functions.php. i think some error with my code, can you guys tell me whats wrong with the code? check this file: https://pastebin.com/84LgBTu9

Comment: Could be a missing }. You'd need to check the code carefully. An editor that autoformats is beneficial in tracking down those kinds of typos. Good luck!